# JPlayer2.6.0 can not work in IE7/8 when i deploye app in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7, jplayer

JPlayer2.6.0 can not work in IE7/8 when i deploye this WAR app in tomcat7.but it works when i deploy it with eclipse.this two tomcat7 is the same tomcat. why? can anyone help me?